# Using java generics to ensure that argument received is same as class or subtype thereof

Tags: java, generics

I have a newbie question.

```
interface Animal {
    void partner(Animal other);
}

class Lion implements Animal {
    int areaUnderControl;
    @Override
    public void partner(Animal other) {
        Lion lion = (Lion) other;
        this.areaUnderControl += lion.areaUnderControl; 
    }
}

class Human implements Animal {
    int money;
    @Override
    public void partner(Animal other) {
        Human human = (Human) other;
        this.money += human.money;
    }
}
```

I want that the partner method in the concrete implementations only receive parameters of its type or its subtype. One solution is to use generics to define Animal as:

```
interface Animal<T extends Animal<T>> {
    void partner(T other);
}

class Lion implements Animal<Lion> {
    int areaUnderControl;
    @Override
    public void partner(Lion other) {
        this.areaUnderControl += other.areaUnderControl; 
    }
}

class Human implements Animal<Human> {
    int money;
    @Override
    public void partner(Human other) {
        this.money += other.money;
    }
}
```

However someone can still abuse this as

```
class Bear implements Animal<Lion> {
    int honey;
    @Override
    public void partner(Lion other) {
        this.honey += other.areaUnderControl; //Problem
    }
}
```

where a Bear is aspiring to partner with Lion. Is there someway that I can tie it to the type and subtypes of *this*

I tried searching through the existing questions and somehow I feel the design of the interface itself may be flawed. If someone can point out why this is wrong or the right way to achieve this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The problem seems to be with the interface itself. Needless to say, why is Bear implements Animal<Lion> a concern for you? Implementation should be under your control, will that even be a problem?

Comment: @ardentsonata I am just trying to see if there is a way to avoid the clients of the interface to avoid shooting themselves in the foot.

Comment: That's the pitfall of java generics unfortunately. And nothing that can be enforced or checked at compile time unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to enforce this at the interface level, because there is no reason to do so from a *type safety* point of view. So what if it's possible to define a `class Bear implements Animal<Lion>`? By itself, it's type safe (i.e. will not throw unexpected ClassCastException, etc.) -- that's the whole point that Generics is for.

In fact, from a type safety point of view, most likely you just need `interface Animal<T>` (analogous with `interface Comparable<T>`). Yes, this will allow someone to define strange classes that implement Animal with a type parameter that is a completely unrelated class. So what? There is nothing wrong with that *per se*.

In the places that *use* this interface, they can enforce the relationship that you want, like `public <T extends Animal<? super T>> void someMethodThatUsesAnimal(T animal)`. Because it is only in the places that *use* it that really cares whether the `partner` method takes itself as a parameter. This is analogous to how `Comparable` is used (e.g. `public <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)`)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can enforce this at compile time. Please look at the workaround which ensures this at run time.

```
class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SnowLion lion = new SnowLion();
        // This will throw IllegalArgumentException
        Bear bear = new Bear();
    }
}

abstract class Animal<T extends Animal<T>> {

    protected Animal(Class<T> implClazz) {
        if (!implClazz.isAssignableFrom(getClass())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

    abstract void partner(T other);
}

class Lion extends Animal<Lion> {

    public Lion() {
        super(Lion.class);
    }

    int areaUnderControl;

    @Override
    public void partner(Lion other) {
        this.areaUnderControl += other.areaUnderControl;
    }
}

class Human extends Animal<Human> {
    public Human() {
        super(Human.class);
    }

    int money;

    @Override
    public void partner(Human other) {
        this.money += other.money;
    }
}

class Bear extends Animal<Lion> {

    public Bear() {
        super(Lion.class);
    }

    int honey;

    @Override
    public void partner(Lion other) {
        this.honey += other.areaUnderControl; // Problem
    }
}

class SnowLion extends Lion {

    int snowAreaUnderControl;

    public SnowLion() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void partner(Lion other) {
        this.snowAreaUnderControl += other.areaUnderControl;
    }
}
```

I got this idea from [Java generics to enforce return type of abstract method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627581/java-generics-to-enforce-return-type-of-abstract-method/1627633#1627633)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This check explicitly denies the possibility of further inheritance from a specific type of Animal. For example, you couldn't create `class SnowLion extends Lion`, since its class would differ at runtime from Lion.

Comment: Modified the answer to take care of this. Please have a look.

Comment: Better. The `.equals()` check is now redundant - you could just check `if (!implClazz.isAssignableFrom(getClass()))`.

Answer (score 0):

newacct gave a very nice answer to the question and drawing its analogy to comparable.  The duty of ensuring that the two objects for partnering is delegating to the place of use viz. Animals in this case. Stating here with example code for clarity:

```
interface Animal<T> {
    void partner(T other);
}

class Lion implements Animal<Lion> {
    int areaUnderControl;

    @Override
    public void partner(Lion other) {
        this.areaUnderControl += other.areaUnderControl;
    }
}

class Human implements Animal<Human> {
    int money;

    @Override
    public void partner(Human other) {
        this.money += other.money;
    }
}

// Naughty bear
class Bear implements Animal<Lion> {
    int honey;

    @Override
    public void partner(Lion other) {
        this.honey += other.areaUnderControl;// problem
    }
}

class Animals {
    static <T extends Animal<? super T>> void partner(T animal1, T animal2) {
        animal1.partner(animal2);
    }
}


public class CaptureGenericsFunTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Lion lion1 = new Lion();
    lion1.areaUnderControl = 10;
    Lion lion2 = new Lion();
    lion2.areaUnderControl = 20;
    Bear bear = new Bear();
    bear.honey = 100;

    Animals.partner(lion1, lion2); // ok
    Animals.partner(lion1, bear); // compilation problem
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce this every time someone passes an `Animal` object as a parameter to a method. For example, if you maintain a list of all animals in your zoo somewhere, you can extend the class of the list and override its `add()` method with this generic version:

```
@Override
public <AnimalType extends Animal<AnimalType>> void add(AnimalType animal) {
    super.add(animal);
}
```

This method will accept any `Animal<itself>`, but no `Animal<something else>`. That way, it's still possible for someone to define a `Bear extends Animal<Lion>` but that bear will no longer be allowed in your zoo, because if you pass it as an argument to `add()` that call will throw a compile-time *bound mismatch* error.

What's much trickier is to enforce this same convention for the return type of a method. The verdict is still out on that one as of now:

[Enforcing Java method return type to fit certain Generic signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637882/enforcing-java-method-return-type-to-fit-certain-generic-signature#comment18710758_13637882)

Answer (score 0):

You could also define your interface like this:

```
interface Animal<T extends Animal<T>> {
    void partner(T other);

    /**
     * Please implement with just this line in it:<br/><br/>
     * &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<code>return this;</code>
     * @return <code>this</code>
     */
    T returnThis();
}
```

Then anyone implementing this class will have to provide a method that returns an object of the type of the specified animal. So, your pretend-bear will have to provide `Lion returnThis()` and if he follows the documentation and implements it simply as `return this`, that will throw a *Type mismatch* error.

This still doesn't protect against someone who deliberately wants to mess with things and then returns a `new Lion()` instead of `this`, but it will definitely catch errors in which you simply tried to copy the `Bear extends Animal<Bear>` class to make the class `Grizzly` and forgot to change the resulting `Grizzly extends Animal<Bear>` to `Grizzly extends Animal<Grizzly>`. (If you actually want to allow grizzlys to be partnered with black bears is another issue that the board of your zoo will have to decide...)