# Enforcing Java method return type to fit certain Generic signature

Tags: java, generics, methods, return-type

Let's say I have this interface:

```
interface Foo<T extends Foo<T>> { // ... }
```

And the following three classes implementing it:

```
class TrueFoo  implements Foo<TrueFoo > { // ... }

class FalseFoo implements Foo<FalseFoo> { // ... }

class WrongFoo implements Foo<FalseFoo> { // ... }
//                            ^^^^^^^^ this here is wrong, only 
//                                     Foo<WrongFoo> should be allowed
```

What would the method signature of the following method need to be to enforce that I can return objects of type TrueFoo or FalseFoo, but not WrongFoo...

```
public ???? getFoo(boolean which) {
    return which ? new TrueFoo() : new FalseFoo();
}
```

The following don't work:

- This allows me to also return a new WrongFoo():

  ```
  public Foo<?> getFoo(boolean which) {
      return which ? new TrueFoo() : new FalseFoo();
  }
  ```
- This doesn't allow me to return anything *(explanation following)*:

  ```
  public <FooType extends Foo<FooType>> FooType getFoo(boolean which) {
      return which ? new TrueFoo() : new FalseFoo();
  }
  ```

  The problem is that the type of FooType is determined by the context in which I call the function `getFoo()` and not by the object I am actually trying to return.

Enforcing this signature when *calling* a method is easy, by the way:

```
public <FooType extends Foo<FooType>> void test(FooType foo) {
    // Do something with foo
}
```

This will give you a bound mismatch error if you try to call it with an instance of  WrongFoo.

Makes me think there should be a way to do this for method return types as well.

Or is there a way to enforce this signature already in the interface definition for Foo?

**EDIT:**

To help visualize what this interface is supposed to do, you can for example think of this version of it:

```
interface CanCopy<Type extends CanCopy<Type>> {
    public Type copy();
}
```

Clearly a class like `Foo implements CanCopy<Bar>` doesn't make any sense, only `Foo implements CanCopy<Foo>` or `Bar implements CanCopy<Bar>`.

**EDIT 2:**

Just as proof-of-concept that solutions exist, I could define myself the following helper class:

```
class FooResult {
    private final Foo<?> foo;

    public <FooType extends Foo<FooType>> FooResult(FooType foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <FooType extends Foo<FooType>> FooType getFoo() {
        return (FooType) foo;
    }
}
```

Then I can require my getFoo method to be of this type:

```
public FooResult getFoo(boolean which) {
    return which ? new FooResult(new TrueFoo()) : new FooResult(new WrongFoo());
}
```

That way, I will not be able to return a WrongFoo from my get method.

But this, clearly, is a little too convoluted to be as elegant as Java Generics usually tend to make code (in my experience)... So, can this be shortened somehow?

**EDIT 3:**

I found another way to provide a check for someone implementing the interface by defining it like this:

```
interface Foo<FooType extends Foo<FooType>> { 
    // Other interface definitions

    /**
     * Please implement with just this line in it:<br/><br/>
     * &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<code>return this;</code>
     * @return <code>this</code>
     */
    public FooType returnThis();
}
```

Now, if someone tries to implement the WrongFoo class as described above, he will have to provide the method `FalseFoo returnThis()` and if he simply implements it as `return this` as requested in the doctype, that line will throw an error.

It's not a guarantee, but it's a pretty good dummy-check against mistakes that come from careless copying of a class... And in a case where a message with this signature is required anyways, it would be a great solution.

Any more ideas?

Comment: This is an interesting question but its really confusing to follow. Instead of trying to be so generic, maybe throw in some real names. Those foos are hard to follow

Comment: @hbtest True... I'm trying to think if there is something better that actually makes sense to think about in this way... Any ideas?

Comment: Is this just a generic question or did you actually have a situation for this? I assumed you encountered this in a situation and if so just post that.

Comment: I did encounter it in my code, but the context is quite involved and I've tried to distill the question down to the actual problem-issue as much as possible.

Comment: Its hard for me to help you out because I was having trouble understanding it myself...sorry

Comment: Let me try to add a clarifying example... One sec...

Comment: @hbtest Does this make it easier to think about? (Let's hope this doesn't lead to people trying to problem-solve how to implement CanCopy in a better way, which is usually what happens...)

Comment: No realistic solution exists that will _force_ users to do what you want.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I found one and added it as an edit to the question. Not super-elegant and I'm not sure I would want to resort to it, but it definitely achieves what I'm looking for. (Actually... This is for a library for my own use... I'd never try to force someone else to do what I want, but for "present-me" to force "future-me" (who may not be as deeply into the problem at that time) to not make mistakes that turn into run-time errors, I think, is a good idea...)

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work, either.  You can have `class FalseFoo implements Foo<FalseFoo>`, and then `class WrongFoo extends FalseFoo`, in which case `WrongFoo implements Foo<FalseFoo>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using java generics to ensure that argument received is same as class or subtype thereof](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426517/using-java-generics-to-ensure-that-argument-received-is-same-as-class-or-subtype)

Comment: @LouisWasserman Actually it does prevent that case also... Try it...

Comment: @newacct It's similar, but goes a step further. One possible answer to that question is already contained in my question (added it as an answer there as well just now). That question asks about the interface and I am asking about method return types.

Answer (score 3):

The issue you're having with generics is the symptom, not the problem:  You're asking your interface to become dependent upon your concrete implementation.  If you want your getFoo interface method to return something that is not a WrongFoo, you must return something that is a TrueFoo or a FalseFoo but not a WrongFoo.  Your class hierarchy does not have this particular indirection.

To add it, you would need to do something like the following:

```
class TrueFoo extends SpecialFoo {...}

class FalseFoo extends SpecialFoo {...}

class WrongFoo implements Foo<WrongFoo> {...}

class SpecialFoo implements Foo<SpecialFoo> {  
  SpecialFoo getFoo() {...}
}
```

Remember that Java supports covariant return types, so by returning SpecialFoo we can implement the contract created in the Foo interface: `Foo getFoo() {...}`

If you were to need behavior specific to TrueFoo and FalseFoo, you could further parameterize SpecialFoo, and so on, [turtles all the way down](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aTurtlesAllTheWayDown2.png).

**EDIT:**

After reading your edit, I don't believe what you're trying to accomplish is supported by the language.  It seems like you want to constrain the interface based on the concrete implementation, which would by definition make it not an interface.  I think the following example is as close as you're going to get to what you're looking for:

```
interface CanCopy<T extends CanCopy<T>> {
       T copy();
}

interface FooCanCopy extends CanCopy<Foo> {
}

interface BarCanCopy extends CanCopy<Bar> {
}

class Foo implements FooCanCopy {

    public Foo copy() {
        return null;
    }
}

class Bar implements BarCanCopy {

    public Bar copy() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I hope its clear now why the approach doesn't work, even here you still can't prevent someone from doing something like `class Baz implements FooCanCopy` either.  I'd be more curious to know why you're trying to do this? If its to protect developers from making a mistake, there might be other options, i.e. introspecting unit tests or packaging changes.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work in the case I'm using it (see for example the edit I made to the original question; I would lose the fact that the copy is actually of the same type as the original). I can't condense the different implementations of my "Foo" into one least common denominator super-type and have the whole thing still be useful. In my case that would be equivalent to actually just working with "Object".

Comment: See my last note, in this case you would parameterize SpecialFoo<S> with its own parameter like so: `class TrueFoo extends SpecialFoo<TrueFoo>`, etc. So your `getFoo` would look like `SpecialFoo<TrueFoo> getFoo() {...}` in the `TrueFoo` class.

Comment: Unfortunately even that won't work in my case. My actual problem is really very close (conceptually) to the requirements that the CanCopy situation I described above poses.

Comment: I came up with some way to get closer to an answer I might be hoping for, maybe. If you have time, take a quick look at my EDIT 2 to the question and see if this might help?