# Returning instance of abstract method

Tags: java

I have an abstract class with a method that i would like to return 'this' of the classes' subclasses. When i'm using the method i don't want it to return the object casted as MyClass and me have to recast it back to what it really is. Is there a pretty way of doing this with a generic?

```
abstract public class MyClass{

    public <aSubClassOfMyClass> doSomething(){

        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627581/java-generics-to-enforce-return-type-of-abstract-method?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the class generic using the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
abstract public class MyClass<T extends MyClass<T>>{    
    public T doSomething(){    
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: IntelliJ is telling me that T and the 'this' class are incompatible types

Comment: @David: Yes; you'll need to cast  (which will introduce another warning about unchecked casting).  Java's type system is not powerful enough to express this correctly.